# get select button id from table

Tags: jquery

I create the dynamic table and append like this,

```
var table = $('table#mytable');
var row = "<tr><td> <input name='Name' id='Name' type='text' /></td>" +
    "<td> <input name='Email' id='Email' type='text' /> *</td>" +
    "<td> <select id='selectid1'></select> </td>" +
    "<td> <select id='selectid2'><option>--Select--</option><option>Option1</option><option>Option2</option><option>Option3</option></select> *</td>" +
    "<td> <select name='sometext' multiple='multiple'><option>text1</option> <option>text2</option><option>text3</option><option>text4</option> <option>text5</option></select></td>" +
    "<td> <select name='sometext' multiple='multiple'><option>text1</option> <option>text2</option><option>text3</option><option>text4</option> <option>text5</option></select>*</td>" +
    "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check' value='yes'>Accept Terms<br></td> *" +
    "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male<br><input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td>*"+
    "<td> <input type='button' id='btnAdd'  value='ValidateControls' /> </td>" +
    "</tr>";
var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');
table.append(row);
```

BODY

```
    <table id="mytable"></table>
```

Now,I need to get the Selectbox Id using jquery .How to do this

Comment: Can you please explain more....

Comment: @MilindAnantwar second select box need to get selectid2

Comment: Why do you need to get it? It's hardcoded to always be `#selectid2`? This question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to add some functionality using document load function

Comment: @User: on what basis you want that particular select box

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what are you trying to achieve but if you want to get the `id` of second select in your table then one way is to use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**:

```
var id = $('#mytable select').eq(1).prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear for me, because in your table more than one `select` exist and some of them have `ID` and some not.

So, here i provide solutions to get all select box :

```
var ids = [];
$('#mytable tr td select').each(function(){
  ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
  //ids.push($(this).prop('id'));
});
alert(ids.join(','));
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wE2q/)

OR If you want to get specific one, than you can use index.

```
var elemid = $('#mytable tr td select')[0].prop('id');
```